# How do I rotate multiple bones based on the origin of one bone in pose mode?

Tags: bones

Novice here. I know this question is likely been asked before, but I could not find the answer.

So basically what happens now is shown as the picture below:

[image: current bone rotation be like]

I want to do an animation that the character rotates her left leg forward. I selected multiple bones from the foot to the thigh, and I expect them to rotate based on my last selection (which is the bone attached to the thigh), however it seems like they rotate based on the center of all three of them.

What I have tried:

- Let the calf and foot bone be children of the thigh bone. (basically just Ctrl+P, set parent to bone/object, I tried both, and my last selection was the thigh bone )
- Set my cursor to the root of the thigh bone.

However both methods do not seem to work. I wonder what is a quick solution to this?

Comment: You should investigate Inverse kinematics rigging. There are various YT tutorials for rigging legs with IK such as [this](https://youtu.be/npQsp2CoraQ) one for instance.

Comment: @JohnEason Thanks, I will take a look at it.

Comment: To answer you first query, if you select and  try to rotate all 3 leg bones together they will try to rotate around the median point of all 3 if you have the pivot point set to 'Median Point' (linked circles on the top toolbar).

Comment: @JohnEason Appreciated, this kinda solved my problem.